Is there any way to still use touch.facebook.com
I wanted to know if someone can give me a hand. Until today I was using touch.facebook.com in Mozilla Firefox version 48, but it is no longer available.
So far I have tried in these versions:
In these it tells me that “browser is not supported”.
49.0.1
48.0.2
48.0.1
48.0
47.0
43.0b9
37.0
1.5.0.3
33.0
And in these directly redirects to facebook.com
69.0b9
58.0
I also tried in the last available version of Safari for Windows, but it is so obsolete that the Login button does not work.
I couldn't get it to work in older versions of Chrome or Internet Explorer either.
Anyway, if anyone still knows how to login to touch.facebook.com either from mobile or from pc, I will be very grateful.
